# rescaling a png

Tags: graphics

```
 \documentclass{exam}
 \usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}   
 \begin{tabular}{ c c }
  \includegraphics{Questions/car.png}[scale=\factor , scale= 0.2]  & 
 \includegraphics{Questions/car.png}[scale=\factor , scale= 0.2] \\
  \includegraphics{Questions/car.png}[scale=\factor , scale= 0.2] & 
\includegraphics{Questions/car.png}[scale=\factor , scale= 0.2] \\
   \includegraphics{Questions/car.png}[scale=\factor , scale= 0.2] &  \\
 \end{tabular}
 (Monday)

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

I know could resize the image itself but I don't understand why scaling is not working, any help? Sorry I know the image will not work for people as is on my comp but the general code is there for people to advise if it's enough.

Comment: The syntax should be `\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-duck}`, not `\includegraphics{example-image-duck}[scale=0.2]`. And if you want to use a macro for the scaling factor, you need to define it in your document.

Comment: You might find https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-07 interesting to read.

Comment: as you have not defined `\factor` it is hard to guess what you intended `scale=\factor ` to do (simply deleting it would remove the error)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the `scale=...` option to set the images' widths, I'd use the `width=...` option. E.g., along the lines of

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' environment and 'X' column type

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} XX @{}}
\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{Questions/car.png}  & 
  \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{Questions/car.png} \\[3ex] % extra vertical whitespace
\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{Questions/car.png} & 
  \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{Questions/car.png} \\[3ex] % extra vertical whitespace
\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{Questions/car.png} &  
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```